# Can I pull from git when local and remote changed the same files but not the same lines

Tags: bash, git

If I have a file in git that I changed the first and on remote I changed the last line, like so:

test.py - local

```py
+ import test
import bla
...
...
...
```

test.py - remote

```py
import bla
...
...
...
+ print(done)
```

If I try to git pull I get an error that I have local changes that will be removed, but if I stash them and apply them after it is working great.

```sh
# option 1:
git pull # error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten

# option 2:
git stash
git pull
git stash apply # work great without conflict
```

**Is there a way to tell git to behave like the second option in one command?**

Comment: You can declare an alias or just run them in the same command: `git stash && git pull && git stash apply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git pull` has an option `--autostash` which stashes local modification first, and applies the stash entry when done. However it works only with `--rebase` or `-r`. In your case you can use `git pull -r --autostash` in one command.

The default pull is merge-pull. `--rebase` indicates rebase-pull which applies the local unpushed commits onto `FETCH_HEAD`. Merge and rebase work differently. You may not want rebase in some cases. Anyway, when you think it's appropriate to make rebase-pull, `-r --autostash` does the job.

You can also define an alias or a function to do the job in one command.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will wait little more time to see if someone have an idea to do it without rebase before marking as answer